# Twilio Flex and Salesforce High Velocity Sales Integration

Tags: twilio, high-velocity-sales

My issue is that when I make a phone call from the Work Queue in High Velocity Sales, it successfully makes a call through the Twilio Flex Open CTI integration, creates two tasks, one [Started] and one [Completed] but then stays in the same step in the Sales Cadence. I have even created a Log a Call record with the necessary Call Result that would advance the record in the Sales Cadence, with no result. I have set these call result stage advancements in the HVS settings on the back end.

Our preference would be that it would automatically log this call with an option to set the correct Call Result advancing the Sales Cadence to the next step. I am having trouble though figuring out how these can work together, whether this is needed in Twilio Flex integration, or something that needs to be developed in Salesforce.

Articles that I think would be helpful are the following:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_hvs_lex.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.hvs_considerations_phone_integration.htm&type=5